# Powershell issue with do while loop

Tags: powershell

I've got a simple bit of code that looks for a string in a series of log files.

If it finds the string, it should exit the loop (nested inside another loop as part of a function) with $buildlogsuccess = 'True'

If it can't find the string, it should exit and return $buildlogsuccess = 'False'

The select-string statement itself works, however it looks like there's something wrong with the below code:

```
        $logArr = gci C:\build\Logs | where {($_.name -like 'install*.log') -and (! $_.PSIsContainer)} | select -expand FullName
        $count = ($logArr).count
        Foreach ($log in $logArr) {
            Do {
            $count -= 1
            $buildlogsuccess = [bool](select-string -path $log -simplematch $buildstring)
            If (($buildlogsuccess)) {break}
            } while ($count -gt '0')
        }
```

When one of the logs has the string, the loop finishes and should return $buildlogsuccess as 'True'.

If I check $log it shows the file that I know has the string (in this instance C:\build\Logs\Installer1.log).

Strangely, at this point $count shows as having a value of -1?

If I take the string out of that file and run again it also exits and returns the correct variable value (and shows the $log variable as the last file in $logArr as expected), but this time $count shows as -24.

My code is also returning $buildlogsuccess as 'False' when the string is present in one of the log files.

Re-tested `[bool](select-string -path $log -simplematch $buildstring)` by manually populating $log (with a file that has that string) and $buildstring and get 'True' as expected when using

> [bool](select-string -path $log -simplematch $buildstring)

Note: Variables it uses:

> $buildstring  = "Package
>   'F:\xxx\Bootstrap\apackage\Installsomething.xml' processed
>   successfully"

Any help identifying where I've gone wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be greatly simplified:

```
$buildlogsuccess = Select-String -SimpleMatch -Quiet $buildstring C:\build\Logs\install*.log
```

The above assumes that there are no *directories* that match `install*.log`; if there's a chance of that, pipe the output of `Get-ChildItem -File C:\build\Logs -Filter install*.log` to `Select-String` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`Do-while` will first do the thing, then check the `while` statement. You're iterating over `n` files. It doesn't check the value of `$count` before it executes that portion.

So let's say the first file does not contain the string you're looking for. It will (correctly) decrement the `$count` variable to zero, and then it moves on to the next `$log` in `$logArr`.

Now for each next file in the folder it will decrement `$count`, and then exit the loop when it sees that `$count` is not greater than 0.

I don't know why you're using the `do-while` loop at all here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Norsk

I over-complicated for myself.

This worked:

```
        $logArr = gci C:\build\Logs | where {($_.name -like 'install*.log') -and (! $_.PSIsContainer)} | select -expand FullName
        $count = ($logArr).count
        Foreach ($log in $logArr) {
            $buildlogsuccess = [bool](select-string -path $log -simplematch $buildstring)
            If ($buildlogsuccess) {break}
        }
```